# How do I mail pdf as an attachment generated by Dompdf in php?

Tags: php, codeigniter, pdf, sendmail

How do I mail pdf as an attachment generated by Dompdf in php?

Code for generating pdf is like this.

```
$this->load->plugin('to_pdf');

pdf_create($this->load->view('print_registration', $data, true), 'Title : Registration Form');
```

Comment: As for the mail part, CI has a built-in email library which handles attachment; refers to the manual for the usage

Answer (score 0):

You could use a library such as [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/) or [SwiftMailer](http://swiftmailer.org/).

Comment: There's also the Email library in Codeigniter. For just a mail with an attachment it could be enough

Answer (score 0):

Use dompdf to write your PDF file to disk. Then, use the file as an attachment and send the email.

Or

Just save the file that is generated with dompdf and then you can attach it to an email using CodeIgniter's attach() method from the email class.

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/email.html